# Extends constructor from class in android

Tags: android

I have a class where I extend `LinearLayout`. 
I have three constructors:

```
public IconsComponent(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public IconsComponent(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);

}
public IconsComponent(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}
```

and this is my init:

```
public void init(final Context context, ExtraView patient) {
        this.context = context;
        View root = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.icons_component_view, null);
        LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);



        vitalParamsIcon = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.icons_component_vital_params);
        vitalParamsIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startMetActivity(getContext());
            }
        });

        addView(root, layoutParams);
    }
```

as you can see my init has extra param: ExtraView. How can I set this params to constructors? I need that param because I want to get some data from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your layout will get instantiated (constructor called) with all the XML parameters in the parameter `attrs` as an `AttributeSet`. You need to get the custom paramters out of there and do what you want with them. See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) for help writing custom layouts/views.

Answer (score 0):

The 3 constructors is needed for use on xml layouts, so if you don't instantiate this layout via xml, you can freely create a new constructor with the parameters you need and use it in code.

But if you use a xml layout, you need to create a parameter for the layout in xml and read that on the constructor.

PS: Maybe you cut something from your code example, because you don't use the extra parameter you want.

Comment: I have this layout in xml. Look on init(final Context context, ExtraView patient), this is this param.

Comment: what is ExtraView? Is it a new Class you defined that gets inflated on your View hierarchy?

Comment: yes, ExtraView is object from other class where I have some data which I want to get in this class